# python sorted and chain - django querysets

Tags: python, django

I have this

```
b_articles = tc.tc_buch_articles.all()
j_articles = tc.tc_journal_articles.all()                
joined = itertools.chain(b_articles, j_articles)
sorter = lambda x: x.article_in_collection__year if hasattr(x, 'article_in_collection__year') else x.article_in_journal__year
articles = sorted(joined, key = sorter, reverse=True)
```

below are my models

I am getting the error:

```
'EntryArticleInCollection' object has no attribute 'article_in_journal__year'
```

I want to achieve this kind of result:

```
a = 1, 3, 8, 10
b = 2, 3, 5, 12
res = 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12
```

models:

```
class TopicCenter(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(Person,related_name="user_tcs")      
  title = models.TextField()
  subtitle = models.TextField()

class ArticleInCollection(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(Person,related_name="user_buchaufsatz")
  title = models.TextField()
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book,related_name="book_aufsatze")    
  added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
  year = models.IntegerField(default=0000)

class ArticleInJournal(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(Person,related_name="user_journalaufsatz")
  title = models.TextField()
  journal = models.ForeignKey(Journal,related_name="journal_aufsatze")
  added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
  year = models.IntegerField(default=0000)

class EntryArticleInCollection(models.Model):
  added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
  lastmodified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
  topiccenter = models.ForeignKey(TopicCenter,related_name="tc_buch_articles")
  article_in_collection = models.ForeignKey(ArticleInCollection,related_name="bucharticle_entries")

class EntryArticleInJournal(models.Model):
  added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
  lastmodified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
  topiccenter = models.ForeignKey(TopicCenter,related_name="tc_journal_articles")
  article_in_journal = models.ForeignKey(ArticleInJournal,related_name="journal_article_entries")
```

Comment: Could you show your model definitions?

Comment: @alecxe i updated the question with my models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this `getattr()` approach:

```
sorter = lambda x: getattr(x, 'article_in_collection', x.article_in_journal).year
```

or:

```
def sorter(x): 
    try: 
        return x.article_in_collection.year 
    except AttributeError: 
        return x.article_in_journal.year
```

The problem with your solution is that you first need to get the `ForeignKey` field and then get the field on the related model via `dot notation`. Double underscore approach would not work in this case.

Comment: it is saying: ``'EntryArticleInCollection' object has no attribute 'article_in_journal'``

Comment: Aah, i see. so there is no deeper lookup in fkeys once i am inside sorted() function? but it must be somehow solvable :(

Comment: @doniyor ok, let's dig it a bit. What are you getting in case of this `sorter`: `sorter = lambda x: x.added`?

Comment: with ``added``, it is working - giving result sorted by added field

Comment: @doniyor thanks, then, what if you sort `b_articles` separately: `sorted(b_articles, key=lambda x: x.article_in_collection.year)`?

Comment: it is giving no errors, but not giving a sorted result.

Comment: @doniyor you've tried with the `year` in the `lambda`, right? (I've edited the comment after posting).

Comment: oh no sorry. let me try this real quick.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52116/discussion-between-doniyor-and-alecxe)